# Undefine a preprocesser directive that is used in another preprocessor directive

Tags: c, header, preprocessor-directive

This is not my exact issue, but an example is as follows

```
// Method 1

#define Function(argument)  (StupidLongArray[argument] + OtherStupidLongArrayName[argument] * WhyAreMyNamesSoLong[argument])
```

or, prefered

```
// Method 2

#define _SLA StupidLongArray
#define _OSLAN OtherStupidLongArrayName
#define _WAMNSL WhyAreMyNamesSoLong

#define Function(argument) (_SLA[argument] + _OSLAN[argument] * _WAMNSL[argument])

#undef _SLA 
...
...
```

My understanding of these preprocessor directions implies that once Function has been defined, I can get rid of _SLA and friends. This is not the case.

How come? Is their a way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way around this. Preprocessor processing basically involves substituting the macro into the original line, then reprocessing it again. So if you call `Function(x)`, it becomes `(_SLA[x] + _OSLAN[x] * _WAMNSL[x])` first, then the `_SLA`, `_OSLAN`, and `_WAMNSL` macros are substituted afterward. If they're not defined at the place where this substitution occurs, they'll be left as is.

Comment: Ah, I was not viewing the substitution process in that manner. Thank you for the response. I suppose I'll just pollute the name space a little. Will accept your answer when the timer closes on it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the posted answer, you could consider rewriting the macro as:

```
#define Function(argument)                     \
  ( StupidLongArray[argument]                  \
    + OtherStupidLongArrayName[argument]       \
    * WhyAreMyNamesSoLong[argument] )
```

This much clearer and easier to read than your version with short, nonsense abbreviations.

Might also be wise to swap the order of appearance so that the multiplication operation is placed before the addition, to make the code easier to read.

As a side note, you should avoid giving identifiers names that start with `_` since that might collide with library identifiers.